# Why is there no International Phonetic Alphabet input method on this site?

Tags: discussion

To be accepted as a serious international linguistics site; it is my opinion that we should implement an input method for the International Phonetic Alphabet, for example the [***Type It IPA Keyboard***](https://ipa.typeit.org/)

Comment: What do you mean by a "rendering program"? You can insert IPA into posts straightforwardly.

Comment: IPA consists of simple Unicode characters. There is nothing to ‘render’ that would require any kind of rendering program. Do you mean an advanced IPA _input_ helper like the [TypeIt IPA keyboard](https://ipa.typeit.org)? If so, that would be useful, but probably beyond what it’s possible to customise for an SE site, I imagine.

Comment: Yes, I have edited my question.

Comment: Edited based on the comments.

Comment: @ColinFine: Technically true, but the same can (also) be said of Hebrew characters, for instance; nevertheless, both [Biblical Hermeneutics](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com) and [Mi Yodeya](http://judaism.stackexchange.com) possess, as one can clearly see, a button for the Hebrew keyboard in their respective answer and question sections.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: See my previous comment, addressed to **Colin Fine**.

Comment: Japanese.SE has [a lot of custom formatting](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806/how-should-i-format-my-questions-on-japanese-language-se) as well. It would be awesome if we could get XSAMPA rendering or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

I have no objection to the addition of whatever character or graphics rendering utility that aids linguists. I object to the various unsupported assertions implied by the phrase "To be accepted as a serious international linguistics site" and the supposed relationship to a built-in typing utility.